Remove rownumber column after pandas groupby/apply
I have this data (multiple queries, each query has multiple variants, each variant has multiple durations):
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "query":    ["q1", "q1", "q1", "q1", "q2" ],
    "variant":  [ "a",  "a",  "b",  "c",  "a" ],
    "duration": [ 50,   40,   30,   20,   90  ],
})

And I would like to have a dataframe that contains for each query, for each variant the fastest duration, and variants in each query are sorted by their duration.
This almost works:
df.groupby("query").apply(
    lambda x: x.groupby("variant").apply(
        lambda x: x.sort_values("duration").head(1)
    , include_groups=False).sort_values("duration")
, include_groups=False)


But I'd like to remove the marked rownumber column. I'm also wondering if there is a better way to get this result.

Don't use nested groupby, this is highly inefficient, instead, sort_values and drop_duplicates:
out = (df.sort_values(by=['query', 'duration', 'variant'])
         .drop_duplicates(['query', 'variant'], ignore_index=True)
       )

Output:
  query variant  duration
0    q1       c        20
1    q1       b        30
2    q1       a        40
3    q2       a        90

Or, if the final order of the rows doesn't matter, groupby.idxmin:
out = df.loc[df.groupby(['query', 'variant'])['duration'].idxmin()]

Output:
  query variant  duration
1    q1       a        40
2    q1       b        30
3    q1       c        20
4    q2       a        90

For the sake of completeness, you would have needed to add a droplevel to your approach:
df.groupby("query").apply(
    lambda x: x.groupby("variant").apply(
        lambda x: x.sort_values("duration").head(1)
    , include_groups=False).sort_values("duration")
, include_groups=False).droplevel(-1)

Output:
               duration
query variant          
q1    c              20
      b              30
      a              40
q2    a              90


Simply make multi-indexed DataFrame and sort by duration column:
df.set_index(['query', 'variant']).sort_values("duration")

